# Callback functions in PHP < 5.3

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have an multidimensional array and want to do usort in zendframework.**

Following code work in PHP 5.3+, but not for the lower versions because of the callback function in `usort`.

```
usort($array, function (array $a, array $b) {
    return date('Ymdhis',$a['time']) - date('Ymdhis',$b['time']); 
});
```

So instead of the callback function how can I divide it and use it from external function call in ZEND FRAMEWORK.

In normal PHP script individual call is working as below.

```
usort($array, 'usortcallback');

function usortcallback(array $a, array $b) {
    return date('Ymdhis',$a['time']) - date('Ymdhis',$b['time']);
});
```

But I want workable code for Zend Framework.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: There is no reason to support ancient PHP versions nowadays!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**create_function()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php), that will fork for older PHP too.

```
$callback = create_function(
    '$a, $b',
    'return date("Ymdhis",$a["time"]) - date("Ymdhis",$b["time"]);'
);

usort($array, $callback);
```